# Measure all views load time

Tags: android, performance, windows-phone-8, blackberry

Is there a chance to measure all views load time? I mean time beetween click application icon and load all staff such as maps and results from APIs connection. I'm intrested on Android, Windows Phone and BlackBerry platform.

Comment: If you are talking about Application Launch time, in Android in LogCat, you can get this Application Launch time information.

Comment: Ok, but what about Windows Phone and BlackBerry?